# Appending a variable using a number based on shuffle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to create a quiz, and have most of the script done.

The quiz asks if something is a letter of the alphabet, user can select yes/no. when this is correct, it appends a further, more specific set of answers.

Ie, if the letter is b, the first answer is yes, it is a letter of the alphabet,

the second set of questions is : is this letter a-m, or m-z.  if you select a-m, this give an alert that you are correct, if you select m-z you get an error that you are incorrect.

if you select correctly, 6 more options append, :

The letter is closer to A than M

The letter is closer to M than Z

The letter is N

The letter is closer to Z than N

I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am  wrong

Using the example of  the letter B, - The correct option is "The letter is closer to A than M".

all of that works, now, what I could use some help with,

**I would like those last 6 options to append in a shuffled order.**

I use shuffle elsewhere on the page, but I cant quite get these to shuffle and be able to be clicked , when i was able to shuffle them, the click did not work the same :(
this first code works except does not attempt any shuffling of the last choices.

```js
const sTart =  "<button class='btn btn-success active' id='" 
const sTart2 = "<button class='btn btn-warning active' id='"
const sTart3 = "<button class='btn btn-danger active' id='" 
const sTart4 = "<button class='btn btn-dark active' id='" 
const cLose =  "'>"
const cSpan =  '</button>'



$(document).ready(function () {  
  $('#ArrayD').append(obj[1].fruit)
             $('#YES').click(function()
  {
    if (obj[1].absolute == "YES") 
      {
        alert ("Yes, but where does it belong in the alphabet?")
                $('#secondStep').append("<h2><b>" + obj[1].fruit + " belongs in the following group of letters" + "<br></h2></b>" +sTart + obj[1].belong1 + cLose +  obj[1].belong1 +cSpan + " " + sTart + obj[1].belong2 + cLose + obj[1].belong2 + cSpan)
      }
       else {
        alert ("The selected answer is incorrect. Please try again.")
  }

$('#A-M').click(function()
  { 
      if (obj[1].belong1 == obj[1].belong3) {
        alert ("Your on the right track!")
  $("thirdStep").html("");
      $('#thirdStep').append("<h1> More choices </h1>" + 
          sTart2 + obj[1].belong4a + cLose + obj[1].belong4 + cSpan +  " " +
          sTart3 + obj[1].belong5a + cLose + obj[1].belong5 + cSpan +   " " +
          sTart4 + obj[1].belong6a + cLose + obj[1].belong6 + cSpan + " <br><br>" +
          sTart + obj[1].belong7a + cLose + obj[1].belong7 + cSpan +  " " +
          sTart2 + obj[1].belong8a + cLose + obj[1].belong8 + cSpan) 
      }
      else { alert ("That is not quite right")}

//start the clicks
         $('#4a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong4 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
//
 $('#5a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong5 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
//
 $('#6a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong6 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
 //
  $('#7a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong7 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
  //
   $('#8a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong8 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });

//
  });


$('#N-Z').click(function()
  { 
      if (obj[1].belong2 == obj[1].belong3) {
        alert ("Your on the right track!")
         $("thirdStep").html("");
      $('#thirdStep').append("<h1> More choices </h1>" + 
          sTart2 + obj[1].belong4a + cLose + obj[1].belong4 + cSpan +  " " +
          sTart3 + obj[1].belong5a + cLose + obj[1].belong5 + cSpan +   " " +
          sTart4 + obj[1].belong6a + cLose + obj[1].belong6 + cSpan + " <br><br>" +
          sTart + obj[1].belong7a + cLose + obj[1].belong7 + cSpan +  " " +
          sTart2 + obj[1].belong8a + cLose + obj[1].belong8 + cSpan) 
       }
      else { alert ("That is not quite right")}
        
//start the clicks
         $('#4a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong4 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
//
 $('#5a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong5 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
//
 $('#6a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong6 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
 //
  $('#7a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong7 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
  //
   $('#8a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong8 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });

//
  });



  });
    });



$(document).ready(function () {  
        $('#4a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong4 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
});
            


var obj = [{
    "fruit": "B",
    "absolute": "YES",
    "exclamationEqual":"NO",
    "position": 1,
    "belong1": "A-M",//choice
    "belong2": "N-Z",//choice
    "belong3": "A-M",//answer
    "belong4": "The letter is closer to A than M",//choice2
    "belong5": "The letter is closer to M than A",//choice2
    "belong6": "The letter is N",//choice2
    "belong7": "The letter is closer to Z than N",//choice2
    "belong8": "I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am wrong",//choice2
    "belong9": "The letter is closer to A than M",//answer2
    "belong4a": "4a",
    "belong5a": "5a",
    "belong6a": "6a",
    "belong7a": "7a",
    "belong8a": "8a",
    "belong9a": "TheletterisclosertoAthanM"//spanid answer



  },
     {
    "fruit": "n",
    "absolute": "YES",
    "exclamationEqual":"NO",
    "position": 2,
    "belong1": "A-M",
    "belong2": "N-Z",
    "belong3": "N-Z",
    "belong4": "The letter is closer to A than M",//c2
    "belong5": "The letter is closer to M than A",//c2
    "belong6": "The letter is N",//choice2
    "belong7": "The letter is closer to Z than N",//c2
    "belong8": "I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am wrong",//c2
    "belong9": "The letter is N",//answer 2
    "belong4a": "4a",//sc2
    "belong5a": "5a",//sc2
    "belong6a": "6a",
    "belong7a": "7a",
    "belong8a": "8a",
    "belong9a": "TheletterisN"
  },
  {
    "fruit": "x",
    "absolute": "YES",
    "exclamationEqual":"NO",
    "position": 3,
    "belong1": "A-M",
    "belong2": "N-Z",
    "belong3": "N-Z",
    "belong4": "The letter is closer to A than M",
    "belong5": "The letter is closer to M than A",
    "belong6": "The letter is N",
    "belong7": "The letter is closer to Z than N",
    "belong8": "I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am wrong",
    "belong9": "The letter is closer to Z than N",
    "belong4a": "4a",//sc2
    "belong5a": "5a",//sc2
    "belong6a": "6a",
    "belong7a": "7a",
    "belong8a": "8a",
    "belong9a": "TheletterisclosertoZthanN"

  },
    {
    "fruit": 1,
    "absolute": "NO",
    "exclamationEqual":"YES",
    "position": 4,
    "belong1": "A-M",
    "belong2": "N-Z",
    "belong3": "Supercalifragilisticexpialadocious",
    "belong4": "The letter is closer to A than M",
    "belong5": "The letter is closer to M than A",
    "belong6": "The letter is N",
    "belong7": "The letter is closer to Z than N",
    "belong8": "I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am wrong",
    "belong9": "If you got this to come up, you definitely cheated...",
    "belong9": "The letter is closer to Z than N",
    "belong4a": "4a",//sc2
    "belong5a": "5a",//sc2
    "belong6a": "6a",
    "belong7a": "7a",
    "belong8a": "8a",
    "belong9a": "Ifyougotthistocomeup,youdefinitelycheated"
  }
    ]
;

obj.sort(function (a, b) {return Math.random() - 0.5;});


///
// $(document).ready(function () {  


//    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Quiz </title>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS  & JS--> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<!-- Jquery --> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Toastr Min CSS --> 
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css'> 

<!--Toastr Min JS --> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js'></script>
<!--Font Awesome --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Custom JS and CSS -->
 <script src="./scripts/Jquiz2.2working.js"></script>
<!-- End Custom JS and CSS -->
<style>
body {padding-top:5%; margin-left:5%;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div>

Is:<br>
                    <br><h1><b><span id="ArrayD" style="border:dashed;padding:5px;"> </span></b></h1> a letter of the alphabet?

<div id="btns">
 <br>
<button class="btn btn-info active" caption="Yes" id="YES"> Yes</button> <button class="btn btn-info active" caption="No" id="NO"> No</button>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<span id ="secondStep"></span>
<br>
<br>
<span id ="thirdStep"></span>

 </body>

</html>
```

in my code, B is the best to try with, "1" doesn't do much.

here is what I tried and did not work.(keep hitting run until "B" comes up as letter")

```js
const sTart =  "<button class='btn btn-success active' id='" 
const sTart2 = "<button class='btn btn-warning active' id='"
const sTart3 = "<button class='btn btn-danger active' id='" 
const sTart4 = "<button class='btn btn-dark active' id='" 
const cLose =  "'>"
const cSpan =  '</button>'




  var a = [4, 5, 6, 7,8];
a.sort(function (a, b) {return Math.random() - 0.5;});

;
const fFirst = a[0];
const sSecond = a[1];
const tThird = a[2];
const fFourth = a[3];
const fFifth = a[4]; 



const belongFour = "obj[1].belong" + fFirst;
const belongFive = "obj[1].belong" + sSecond;
const belongSix = "obj[1].belong" + tThird;
const belongSeven = "obj[1].belong" + fFourth;
const belongEight = "obj[1].belong" + fFifth;

const belongFourA = "obj[1].belong" + fFirst + "a";
const belongFiveA = "obj[1].belong" + sSecond + "a";
const belongSixA = "obj[1].belong" + tThird + "a";
const belongSevenA = "obj[1].belong" + fFourth + "a";
const belongEightA = "obj[1].belong" + fFifth + "a";



$(document).ready(function () {  
  $('#ArrayD').append(obj[1].fruit)
             $('#YES').click(function()
  {
    if (obj[1].absolute == "YES") 
      {
        alert ("Yes, but where does it belong in the alphabet?")
                $('#secondStep').append("<h2><b>" + obj[1].fruit + " belongs in the following group of letters" + "<br></h2></b>" +sTart + obj[1].belong1 + cLose +  obj[1].belong1 +cSpan + " " + sTart + obj[1].belong2 + cLose + obj[1].belong2 + cSpan)
      }
       else {
        alert ("The selected answer is incorrect. Please try again.")
  }

$('#A-M').click(function()
  { 
      if (obj[1].belong1 == obj[1].belong3) {
        alert ("Your on the right track!")
  $("thirdStep").html("");
      $('#thirdStep').append("<h1> More choices </h1>" + "<span id='thirdStepA'> </span>" + "<br>");
      
      
      $("#thirdStepA").append(
          sTart2 + obj[1].belong4a + cLose + belongFour + cSpan +  " " +
          sTart3 + obj[1].belong5a + cLose + belongFive + cSpan +   " " +
          sTart4 + obj[1].belong6a + cLose + belongSix + cSpan + " <br><br>" +
          sTart + obj[1].belong7a + cLose + belongSeven + cSpan +  " " +
          sTart2 + obj[1].belong8a + cLose + belongEight + cSpan) }
     
      else { alert ("That is not quite right")}

//start the clicks
         $('#4a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong4 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
//
 $('#5a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong5 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
//
 $('#6a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong6 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
 //
  $('#7a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong7 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
  //
   $('#8a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong8 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });

//
  });


$('#N-Z').click(function()
  { 
      if (obj[1].belong2 == obj[1].belong3) {
        alert ("Your on the right track!")
         $("thirdStep").html("");
      $('#thirdStep').append("<h1> More choices </h1>" + 
          sTart2 + obj[1].belong4a + cLose + obj[1].belong4 + cSpan +  " " +
          sTart3 + obj[1].belong5a + cLose + obj[1].belong5 + cSpan +   " " +
          sTart4 + obj[1].belong6a + cLose + obj[1].belong6 + cSpan + " <br><br>" +
          sTart + obj[1].belong7a + cLose + obj[1].belong7 + cSpan +  " " +
          sTart2 + obj[1].belong8a + cLose + obj[1].belong8 + cSpan) 
       }
      else { alert ("That is not quite right")}
        
//start the clicks
         $('#4a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong4 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
//
 $('#5a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong5 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
//
 $('#6a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong6 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
 //
  $('#7a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong7 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
  //
   $('#8a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong8 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });

//
  });



  });
    });



$(document).ready(function () {  
        $('#4a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong4 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
});
            


var obj = [{
    "fruit": "B",
    "absolute": "YES",
    "exclamationEqual":"NO",
    "position": 1,
    "belong1": "A-M",//choice
    "belong2": "N-Z",//choice
    "belong3": "A-M",//answer
    "belong4": "The letter is closer to A than M",//choice2
    "belong5": "The letter is closer to M than A",//choice2
    "belong6": "The letter is N",//choice2
    "belong7": "The letter is closer to Z than N",//choice2
    "belong8": "I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am wrong",//choice2
    "belong9": "The letter is closer to A than M",//answer2
    "belong4a": "4a",
    "belong5a": "5a",
    "belong6a": "6a",
    "belong7a": "7a",
    "belong8a": "8a",
    "belong9a": "TheletterisclosertoAthanM"//spanid answer



  },
     {
    "fruit": "n",
    "absolute": "YES",
    "exclamationEqual":"NO",
    "position": 2,
    "belong1": "A-M",
    "belong2": "N-Z",
    "belong3": "N-Z",
    "belong4": "The letter is closer to A than M",//c2
    "belong5": "The letter is closer to M than A",//c2
    "belong6": "The letter is N",//choice2
    "belong7": "The letter is closer to Z than N",//c2
    "belong8": "I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am wrong",//c2
    "belong9": "The letter is N",//answer 2
    "belong4a": "4a",//sc2
    "belong5a": "5a",//sc2
    "belong6a": "6a",
    "belong7a": "7a",
    "belong8a": "8a",
    "belong9a": "TheletterisN"
  },
  {
    "fruit": "x",
    "absolute": "YES",
    "exclamationEqual":"NO",
    "position": 3,
    "belong1": "A-M",
    "belong2": "N-Z",
    "belong3": "N-Z",
    "belong4": "The letter is closer to A than M",
    "belong5": "The letter is closer to M than A",
    "belong6": "The letter is N",
    "belong7": "The letter is closer to Z than N",
    "belong8": "I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am wrong",
    "belong9": "The letter is closer to Z than N",
    "belong4a": "4a",//sc2
    "belong5a": "5a",//sc2
    "belong6a": "6a",
    "belong7a": "7a",
    "belong8a": "8a",
    "belong9a": "TheletterisclosertoZthanN"

  },
    {
    "fruit": 1,
    "absolute": "NO",
    "exclamationEqual":"YES",
    "position": 4,
    "belong1": "A-M",
    "belong2": "N-Z",
    "belong3": "Supercalifragilisticexpialadocious",
    "belong4": "The letter is closer to A than M",
    "belong5": "The letter is closer to M than A",
    "belong6": "The letter is N",
    "belong7": "The letter is closer to Z than N",
    "belong8": "I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am wrong",
    "belong9": "If you got this to come up, you definitely cheated...",
    "belong9": "The letter is closer to Z than N",
    "belong4a": "4a",//sc2
    "belong5a": "5a",//sc2
    "belong6a": "6a",
    "belong7a": "7a",
    "belong8a": "8a",
    "belong9a": "Ifyougotthistocomeup,youdefinitelycheated"
  }
    ]
;

obj.sort(function (a, b) {return Math.random() - 0.5;});


///
// $(document).ready(function () {  


//    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Quiz </title>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS  & JS--> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<!-- Jquery --> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Toastr Min CSS --> 
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css'> 

<!--Toastr Min JS --> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js'></script>
<!--Font Awesome --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Custom JS and CSS -->
 <script src="./scripts/Jquiz2.2working.js"></script>
<!-- End Custom JS and CSS -->
<style>
body {padding-top:5%; margin-left:5%;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div>

Is:<br>
                    <br><h1><b><span id="ArrayD" style="border:dashed;padding:5px;"> </span></b></h1> a letter of the alphabet?

<div id="btns">
 <br>
<button class="btn btn-info active" caption="Yes" id="YES"> Yes</button> <button class="btn btn-info active" caption="No" id="NO"> No</button>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<span id ="secondStep"></span>
<br>
<br>
<span id ="thirdStep"></span>

 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of trying to insert a number from the shuffled array, create a new array that you shuffle, and append from that, just like you did with your initial append.

```js
const sTart =  "<button class='btn btn-success active' id='" 
const sTart2 = "<button class='btn btn-warning active' id='"
const sTart3 = "<button class='btn btn-danger active' id='" 
const sTart4 = "<button class='btn btn-dark active' id='"
const sTart5 =  "<button class='btn btn-secondary active' id='"
const cLose =  "'>"
const cSpan =  '</button>'


$(document).ready(function () {  
  $('#ArrayD').append(obj[1].fruit)
             $('#YES').click(function()
  {
    if (obj[1].absolute == "YES") 
      {
        alert ("Yes, but where does it belong in the alphabet?")
                $('#secondStep').append("<h2><b>" + obj[1].fruit + " belongs in the following group of letters" + "<br></h2></b>" +sTart + obj[1].belong1 + cLose +  obj[1].belong1 +cSpan + " " + sTart + obj[1].belong2 + cLose + obj[1].belong2 + cSpan)
      }
       else {
        alert ("The selected answer is incorrect. Please try again.")
  }

$('#A-M').click(function()
  { 
      if (obj[1].belong1 == obj[1].belong3) {
        alert ("Your on the right track!")
  $("thirdStep").html("");
      $('#thirdStep').append("<h1> More choices </h1>" + "<div id='thirdStepA'> </div>" + "<br>");
      //i append a div with thirdstepA
      
      $("#thirdStepA").append(sTart5 +a[0].append + a[0].fruit + cLose + " " + cSpan);
 $('#thirdStepA').append(sTart + a[1].append + a[1].fruit + cLose + " " + cSpan);
 $('#thirdStepA').append(sTart2 +a[2].append + a[2].fruit + cLose + " " + cSpan + "<br><br>");
 $('#thirdStepA').append(sTart3  +a[3].append + a[3].fruit + cLose + " " +cSpan);
  $('#thirdStepA').append(sTart4 +a[4].append + a[4].fruit + cLose + " " + cSpan);
   

//inside thirdstepA I append 4 spans named append 0-4 (5 options).

 $('#append1').append(a[0].fruitname);
 $('#append2').append(a[1].fruitname);
 $('#append3').append(a[2].fruitname);
 $('#append4').append(a[3].fruitname);
  $('#append5').append(a[4].fruitname);
   

//inside the spans i append the fruitname based on the shuffle, viola . shuffle.

         }
     
      else { alert ("That is not quite right")}

//start the clicks
         $('#4a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong4 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
//
 $('#5a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong5 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
//
 $('#6a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong6 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
 //
  $('#7a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong7 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
  //
   $('#8a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong8 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });

//
  });


$('#N-Z').click(function()
  { 
      if (obj[1].belong2 == obj[1].belong3) {
        alert ("Your on the right track!")
         $("thirdStep").html("");
      $('#thirdStep').append("<h1> More choices </h1>" + 
          sTart2 + obj[1].belong4a + cLose + obj[1].belong4 + cSpan +  " " +
          sTart3 + obj[1].belong5a + cLose + obj[1].belong5 + cSpan +   " " +
          sTart4 + obj[1].belong6a + cLose + obj[1].belong6 + cSpan + " <br><br>" +
          sTart + obj[1].belong7a + cLose + obj[1].belong7 + cSpan +  " " +
          sTart2 + obj[1].belong8a + cLose + obj[1].belong8 + cSpan) 
       }
      else { alert ("That is not quite right")}
        
//start the clicks
         $('#4a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong4 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
//
 $('#5a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong5 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
//
 $('#6a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong6 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
 //
  $('#7a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong7 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
  //
   $('#8a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong8 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });

//
  });



  });
    });



$(document).ready(function () {  
        $('#4a').click(function () {
        if (obj[1].belong4 == obj[1].belong9) {
      alert ("You have earned a gold star, that was correct!")}
      else {
        alert ("I think some additional training maybe required, please try again and may the odds ever be in your favor.")
    }
    });
});
            


var obj = [{
    "fruit": "B",
    "absolute": "YES",
    "exclamationEqual":"NO",
    "position": 1,
    "belong1": "A-M",//choice
    "belong2": "N-Z",//choice
    "belong3": "A-M",//answer
    "belong4": "The letter is closer to A than M",//choice2
    "belong5": "The letter is closer to M than A",//choice2
    "belong6": "The letter is N",//choice2
    "belong7": "The letter is closer to Z than N",//choice2
    "belong8": "I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am wrong",//choice2
    "belong9": "The letter is closer to A than M",//answer2
    "belong4a": "4a",
    "belong5a": "5a",
    "belong6a": "6a",
    "belong7a": "7a",
    "belong8a": "8a",
    "belong9a": "TheletterisclosertoAthanM"//spanid answer



  },
     {
    "fruit": "n",
    "absolute": "YES",
    "exclamationEqual":"NO",
    "position": 2,
    "belong1": "A-M",
    "belong2": "N-Z",
    "belong3": "N-Z",
    "belong4": "The letter is closer to A than M",//c2
    "belong5": "The letter is closer to M than A",//c2
    "belong6": "The letter is N",//choice2
    "belong7": "The letter is closer to Z than N",//c2
    "belong8": "I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am wrong",//c2
    "belong9": "The letter is N",//answer 2
    "belong4a": "4a",//sc2
    "belong5a": "5a",//sc2
    "belong6a": "6a",
    "belong7a": "7a",
    "belong8a": "8a",
    "belong9a": "TheletterisN"
  },
  {
    "fruit": "x",
    "absolute": "YES",
    "exclamationEqual":"NO",
    "position": 3,
    "belong1": "A-M",
    "belong2": "N-Z",
    "belong3": "N-Z",
    "belong4": "The letter is closer to A than M",
    "belong5": "The letter is closer to M than A",
    "belong6": "The letter is N",
    "belong7": "The letter is closer to Z than N",
    "belong8": "I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am wrong",
    "belong9": "The letter is closer to Z than N",
    "belong4a": "4a",//sc2
    "belong5a": "5a",//sc2
    "belong6a": "6a",
    "belong7a": "7a",
    "belong8a": "8a",
    "belong9a": "TheletterisclosertoZthanN"

  },
    {
    "fruit": 1,
    "absolute": "NO",
    "exclamationEqual":"YES",
    "position": 4,
    "belong1": "A-M",
    "belong2": "N-Z",
    "belong3": "Supercalifragilisticexpialadocious",
    "belong4": "The letter is closer to A than M",
    "belong5": "The letter is closer to M than A",
    "belong6": "The letter is N",
    "belong7": "The letter is closer to Z than N",
    "belong8": "I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am wrong",
    "belong9": "If you got this to come up, you definitely cheated...",
    "belong9": "The letter is closer to Z than N",
    "belong4a": "4a",//sc2
    "belong5a": "5a",//sc2
    "belong6a": "6a",
    "belong7a": "7a",
    "belong8a": "8a",
    "belong9a": "Ifyougotthistocomeup,youdefinitelycheated"
  }
    ]
;

obj.sort(function (a, b) {return Math.random() - 0.5;});

var a = [{
    "fruit": 1,
    "fruitname" : "The letter is closer to A than M",
    "append":"append"
  },
     {
    "fruit": 2,
    "fruitname" : "The letter is closer to M than A",
    "append":"append"
  },
  {
    "fruit": 3,
    "fruitname" : "The letter is N",
    "append":"append"
  },
  {
    "fruit": 4,
    "fruitname" : "The letter is closer to Z than N",
    "append":"append"
  },
  {
    "fruit": 5,
    "fruitname" : "I needed an example of another option, but you should not chose me because I am wrong",
    "append":"append"
  }
 
    ];

a.sort(function (a, b) {return Math.random() - 0.5;});
```

```css
#append1 { margin-right: 3px; }
#append2 { margin-right: 3px; }
#append3 { margin-right: 3px; }
#append4 { margin-right: 3px; }
#append5 { margin-right: 3px; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Quiz </title>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS  & JS--> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<!-- Jquery --> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Toastr Min CSS --> 
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css'> 

<!--Toastr Min JS --> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js'></script>
<!--Font Awesome --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Custom JS and CSS -->
 <script src="./scripts/Jquiz3.0.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/JquizStyle.css">
<!-- End Custom JS and CSS -->
<style>
body {padding-top:5%; margin-left:5%;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div>

Is:<br>
                    <br><h1><b><span id="ArrayD" style="border:dashed;padding:5px;"> </span></b></h1> a letter of the alphabet?

<div id="btns">
 <br>
<button class="btn btn-info active" caption="Yes" id="YES"> Yes</button> <button class="btn btn-info active" caption="No" id="NO"> No</button>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<span id ="secondStep"></span>
<br>
<br>
<span id ="thirdStep"></span>

 </body>

</html>
```